# How to execute this Excel to XML function in a sub?

Tags: vba, excel

Can someone assist with how I can use this function below that converts my data in an excel file to an XML file in a sub?  When I go to create a macro it by default has it for sub but I need to have it as a function.  I need to be able to use this as maybe a custom button on the toolbar possibly or how can I use it for any spreadsheet I need to convert it from Excel to an XML file?

```
Public Function ExportToXML(FullPath As String, RowName _
As String) As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


Dim colIndex As Integer
Dim rwIndex As Integer
Dim asCols() As String
Dim oWorkSheet As Worksheet
Dim sName As String
Dim lCols As Long, lRows As Long
Dim iFileNum As Integer


Set oWorkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
sName = oWorkSheet.Name
lCols = oWorkSheet.Columns.Count
lRows = oWorkSheet.Rows.Count


ReDim asCols(lCols) As String

iFileNum = FreeFile
Open FullPath For Output As #iFileNum

For i = 0 To lCols - 1
'Assumes no blank column names
If Trim(Cells(1, i + 1).Value) = "" Then Exit For
asCols(i) = Cells(1, i + 1).Value
Next i

If i = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandler
lCols = i

Print #iFileNum, "<?xml version=""1.0""?>"
Print #iFileNum, "<" & sName & ">"
For i = 2 To lRows
If Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = "" Then Exit For
Print #iFileNum, "<" & RowName & ">"

For j = 1 To lCols

    If Trim(Cells(i, j).Value) <> "" Then
       Print #iFileNum, "  <" & asCols(j - 1) & "><![CDATA[";
       Print #iFileNum, Trim(Cells(i, j).Value);
       Print #iFileNum, "]]></" & asCols(j - 1) & ">"
       DoEvents 'OPTIONAL
    End If
Next j
Print #iFileNum, " </" & RowName & ">"
Next i

Print #iFileNum, "</" & sName & ">"
ExportToXML = True
ErrorHandler:
If iFileNum > 0 Then Close #iFileNum
Exit Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert to a `Sub` that could be run from a button you would change it to:

```
Public Sub ExportToXML()
```

This will automatically change the last line to `End Sub`.

`FullPath` and `RowName` will no longer be passed as function-arguments, so would, presumably, need to be read from cells on a worksheet, or perhaps from two `InputBoxes`.

The Sub would no longer return a `Boolean` value, so whatever happens with this value would have to be converted to code within the same Sub (or possibly passed to another Sub).